# When I switch the viewport shading from Solid to Material Preview, some of my textures don't work

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, 3d-view, shaders

When I switch the viewport shading from *Solid* to *Material Preview*, some of my textures don't work.

It only works on pants and shoes, but when I select the jacket and skin (I made sure I selected the correct image texture in my shader editor) it still only shows gray.

[image]

Comment: hello could you please pack your images and share an object that is grey?

Comment: I cannot see all your materials or nodes selected there, just for your information: the _Texture_ option always shows the actively selected **Image Texture** in the material, or if no texture node is selected, the one that was selected last. Meaning: if you have multiple image textures, only the selected one is shown. If you have other texture nodes like _Noise Texture_, _Voronoi Texture_ etc. that are **not images**, the viewport will show the color which is set in the _Material Properties_ under _Viewport Display_. So only if you have or had selected an image texture this will be shown.

Comment: ...and if multiple texture nodes are selected, the image texture must be the active one. And another possibility is that in the _Object Properties_ under _Viewport Display_ > _Display As_ the object is set to _Solid_ instead of _Textured_. In this case the material will also show the color set in the _Material Properties_.